# How to Connect oracle db with JSP

Tags: oracle, jsp

I am a new for JSP and I dont know any information about connection of oracle with JSP can anyone help me step by step?

Comment: show us what have you tried, then we will help you

Comment: I have tried this tutorial but when start the tomcat cmd screen closed suddenly

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/ucp-jdbc-tomcat-355431.html

Comment: @ÇağatayAktaş check log file of tomcat(`/tomcat-installation-dir/logs/`) some exception will be there post it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) for Oracle. Using Java of course, not JSP.

This is a very basic `Database` class I used to use for very little projects.

```
public class Database {

    private String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private Connection conn;
    public static Hashtable errors = null;

    public Database(String serverName, String portNumber, String serviceName, String username, String password, String db) {
        errors = new Hashtable();
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + serviceName;
            Class.forName(driverName);
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            errors.put(db, e);

        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        return this.conn;
    }
}
```

here is a sample of a query

```
Database db = new Database(......); // see Database class construct 
try {
    java.sql.Statement st = db.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FOO");

    while(rs.next()){
        // your code
    }

    rs.close();
    st.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

hope this helps :)